# Google authentication for website using oAuth2.0

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm new to the concept of maintaining user accounts in a website. I read from this [Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) that Google provides an `authentication` and an `authorization` service. I'm only interested in maintaining accounts on my website that users can log into using their Google account username and password. I have an `Express.js` server.

I've spent hours reading about this online and stumbled upon one thing: the `passport-google-oauth` module can be used to do this. But I was unable to find how to get this working with the latest version of Express. Please help.

I would also like to know how to create a project on the Google Developers Console so that the users do not need Google+ accounts to use oauth2 (to get the Client id and secret).

Comment: Have you checked out [this tutorial by Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/series/easy-node-authentication) ? It's pretty good. And it's been updated for Express 4.0.
I could write a working code, but that would be pretty much the same code as in the tutorial so... Plus, you said you were unable to get it working with the latest version of Express ? What exactly is not working ? Show us some code.

For your last question, I didn't really understand it... Users will need to use their Google (whether updated to + or not) accounts to log in, but they will never have to deal with your Client ID

Comment: OP: Sounds like you have some lengthy documentation to read before you try something like this. Good luck.